# Admob ad not showing in my app

Tags: java, android, admob, andengine

Admob ad not showing in my application. I am sensing ad is loading but somehow its not showing because of my layout arrangement. but i couldn't locate it. here is my code

```
protected void onSetContentView() {       

    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
    mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine);

    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,Gravity.CENTER);

    final android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(layoutParams);
    surfaceViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    relativeLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);


    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);        
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "##############");
    adView.refreshDrawableState();
    adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
    frameLayout.addView(adView);
    relativeLayout.addView(frameLayout);
    this.setContentView(relativeLayout, relativeLayoutLayoutParams);

}
```

Comment: Have you consider to build the layout from the xml and not from code ? try this

Comment: im using andengine which is why I cannot use xml to do this. is there any way to that in andengine

Comment: You can do this in XML with andengine. Take a look in the andengine examples. There is a demonstration of how to do this. https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/XMLLayoutExample.java?r=15154df3b77a317ce4e8fd643d4059f536a458c5

Comment: @PlasticSturgeon thanks for the link. i will have a look. but can you tell me why my code not showing admob ad?

Comment: William, below, beat me too it. Your relative layout takes up the whole screen (FILL_PARENT) so the Frame Layout is squashed below. Using XML you would have seen this without needing to compile.

Answer (score 1):

You have told your SurfaceView to FILL_PARENT, so it is taking all the space leaving none for the AdView sibling.

```
final FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,Gravity.CENTER);
```

Note also there is no need for the FrameLayout wrapping the AdView.

I suggest you follow jquery404's advice and define the layout in XML. You'll get a much better understanding of your ui design.